# How do I close a GameMaker game by pressing the back button on an Android device?

Tags: android, game-maker

Is there a way to close the game by pressing the back button on an Android device?

I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On mobile devices, the back button is mapped to the keyboard backspace, `vk_backspace`, which can be used like this:

```
if (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_backspace)) {
    game_end();
}
```

From the manual: https://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/4_gml_reference/controls/device%20input/index.html

Comment: It works! thank so much and sorry by stupid question =)

Comment: NP, remember to always do your research before asking :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `game_end()` when you want to close your game.

Example:

```
if(keyboard_check(vk_escape)) { 
    game_end();
}
```

Comment: First of all, the question is about Android. Android has no Esc key. Second, the question is answered already.

Comment: You can also use the function when the user touches an "exit" button for example.